# Export function not working via JLink in Java8 compiled application

Tags: export, files-and-directories, windows

I have documented the following issue with evaluating the *Export* function via J/Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390977/wolfram-mathematica-kernellink-export-function-not-working-via-jlink-in-java8

The current status is that it could be bound to a Windows update.

Are there any information documentation about issues and workaround in regard to Mathematica and Windows update?